# Select distinct records from MS SQL database when querying row numbers

Tags: sql-server, database

This query returns 5 identical products, because there are 5 keywords associated with the resulting product:

```
SELECT
  products.field1,
  products.field2
FROM products,
     keywords
WHERE products.itemnum = keywords.itemnum
AND products.itemnum = 123
ORDER BY products.field1, products.field2
```

If I put a "`distinct`" after "`select`", then I get 1 result, which is what I want.

However, when I setup my query like this:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM (SELECT
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY products.field1, products.field2) AS rownum,
  products.field1,
  products.field2
FROM products,
     keywords
WHERE products.itemnum = keywords.itemnum
AND products.itemnum = 123) AS qryresults
WHERE rownum >= 1
AND rownum <= 20
```

I get 5 identical products again. There doesn't seem to be anywhere I can put a "distinct" statement to limit it to 1 result. I'm sure the reason is that by adding the row numbers, that doesn't make the results "distinct" anymore.

I am using the technique shown in this query to limit potentially large search results to only 20 records at a time, which greatly reduces overhead and speeds up my query. So if there are 100,000 results, I can easily set this up to return records 90,000-90,020, for example.

MySQL has this kind of thing built-in, but with MS SQL this is the workaround.

However, I am having trouble figuring out how to make it work when I am combining the keywords table.

If I replace the * with a list of columns, then I get an error:

```
The multi-part identifier could not be bound.
```

I'm not sure what else to try. Is there a way to correct this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a CTE to separate the `distinct` and the `ROW_NUMBER()` function:

```
with cte as (select distinct products.field1
                           , products.field2
             from products, keywords
             where products.itemnum=keywords.itemnum and products.itemnum=123), 
    row_n as (select field1
                   , field2
                   , row_number() over (order by field1, field2) as rownum
              from cte)
select field1, field2
from row_n
where rownum>=1 and rownum<=20
```

Comment: I tried that but I get an error: "The multi-part identifier "products.field1" could not be bound."

Comment: I edited the query a while ago. Are you using the version above?

Comment: Oh wait, I neglected to remove the table names from the front of the column names, in the 2nd and 3rd sets. This seems to work now.

Comment: Sweet! Please accept as the answer if it solves your problem.